# Retrain mxnet model in R

Tags: r, mxnet

I have created a neural network with mxnet. Now I want to train this model iteratively on new data points. After I simulated a new data point I want to make a new gradient descent update on this model. I do not want to save the model to an external file and load it again.

I have written the following code, but the weights do not change after a new training step. I also get `NaN` as a training error.

```
library(mxnet)
data <- mx.symbol.Variable("data")
fc1 <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data, num_hidden = 2, no.bias = TRUE)
lro <- mx.symbol.LinearRegressionOutput(fc1)

# first data observation
train.x = matrix(0, ncol = 3)
train.y = matrix(0, nrow = 2)

# first training step
model = mx.model.FeedForward.create(lro,
  X = train.x, y = train.y, initializer = mx.init.uniform(0.001),
  num.round = 1, array.batch.size = 1, array.layout = "rowmajor",
  learning.rate = 0.1, eval.metric = mx.metric.mae)
print(model$arg.params)

# second data observation
train.x = matrix(0, ncol = 3)
train.x[1] = 1
train.y = matrix(0, nrow = 2)
train.y[1] = -33

# retrain model on new data
# pass on params of old model
model = mx.model.FeedForward.create(symbol = model$symbol,
  arg.params = model$arg.params, aux.params = model$aux.params,
  X = train.x, y = train.y, num.round = 1,
  array.batch.size = 1, array.layout = "rowmajor",
  learning.rate = 0.1, eval.metric = mx.metric.mae)
# weights do not change
print(model$arg.params)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. `begin.round` in the second training step must be greater than `num.round` in the first training step, so that the model continues to train.

```
library(mxnet)
data <- mx.symbol.Variable("data")
fc1 <- mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data, num_hidden = 2, no.bias = TRUE)
lro <- mx.symbol.LinearRegressionOutput(fc1)

# first data observation
train.x = matrix(0, ncol = 3)
train.y = matrix(0, nrow = 2)

# first training step
model = mx.model.FeedForward.create(lro,
  X = train.x, y = train.y, initializer = mx.init.uniform(0.001),
  num.round = 1, array.batch.size = 1, array.layout = "rowmajor",
  learning.rate = 0.1, eval.metric = mx.metric.mae)
print(model$arg.params)

# second data observation
train.x = matrix(0, ncol = 3)
train.x[1] = 1
train.y = matrix(0, nrow = 2)
train.y[1] = -33

# retrain model on new data
# pass on params of old model
model = mx.model.FeedForward.create(symbol = model$symbol,
  arg.params = model$arg.params, aux.params = model$aux.params,
  X = train.x, y = train.y, begin.round = 2, num.round = 3,
  array.batch.size = 1, array.layout = "rowmajor",
  learning.rate = 0.1, eval.metric = mx.metric.mae)

print(model$arg.params)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to call `mx.model.FeedForward.create` only once and then use the `fit` function for incremental training?

Comment: I cannot find a fit function in `mxnet`. Which package version do you use? Can you provide some example code please

Comment: Thank you for this way of retraining the mxnet.